# Best way to fill the value of missing index with null in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array which is missing values for some indices, Can you please suggest which is the best way to fill them with either null or 0 something, I have tried possible ways in lodash and nothin seems to be working.

Followed below question and nothing helped

[Filling the missing index and filling its value with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690963/filling-the-missing-index-and-filling-its-value-with-0)

[fill multiple missing values with series based on index values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470620/fill-multiple-missing-values-with-series-based-on-index-values)

[Python - filling a list of tuples with zeros in places of missing indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840403/python-filling-a-list-of-tuples-with-zeros-in-places-of-missing-indexes)

console.log of my array yields below output

`[ 5289, <1 empty item>, 20460, 10860, '189', 'D2989', <1 empty item>, <2 empty items>, '-' ]`

Where I want to fill this as

`[ 5289, null, 20460, 10860, '189', 'D2989', null, null,null, '-' ]`

Comment: "missing values for some indices", does this mean they are "undefined"/"null"? Or are they "empty" slots?

Comment: Why did you look up Python solutions? Sparse arrays will have undefined at uninitialized indices. What's the actual issue? Without any code or context it's difficult to know what you actually want.

Comment: You can't have "missing" array indexes in Javascript. Indexes always start at 0, and the maximum valid index will be determined by the length of the array. Do you want to add more elements at the end of the array, i.e. to pad its length?

Comment: Please share a minimal example of how your array variable looks like.

Comment: Honestly, I am confused there as well But When I do console.log I get as 
`[ 5289,
  <1 empty item>,
  20460,
  10860,
  '189',
  'KA51D2989',
  <1 empty item>,
  <2 empty items>,
  '-' ]`

Comment: And what do you think that means?

Comment: @DaveNewton , I tried looking for solution but most of the solutions are available in Python

Comment: @DaveNewton, I have updated my question with exact Input and Output

Comment: @From where does this array come from?

Comment: @Coldark actually this is the array generated by one of the node library

Comment: Are you relying solely on console log, in a browser, using the default array string representation?

Comment: Perhaps you want something like: `Array.from(arr, v => v ?? null)`, you can change the nullish-coalescing operator to something more browser-friendly if you can't support it

Comment: Actually I am printing the values on the node server and not on browser

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688366/why-are-empty-items-in-my-array-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-them

Comment: @Ron Do you want to preserve existing indices and array length?

Comment: Yes @Coldark , I want to preserve the length and existing indices also

Comment: @Coldark,@DaveNewton,@Nick Parsons thanks for your time, I solved it 
`test.forEach(function (o, index) {
  var len = test.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (test[i] === undefined) {
      test[i] = null;
    }
  }
});`

For sure my question deserves downvotes and I welcome that

Answer (score 3):

Spread operator can convert empty to undefined:

```js
const list = new Array(5);
list[3] = "text";

console.log([...list]);
```

Comment: First of all, `map` doesn't modify the initial array it returns a new one, and apart from that this doesn't work as `map` only iterates over entries that have indices. `undefined` entries in your array have indices - they are not the same as actual empty entries.

Comment: @Coldark I misread. Updated my answer.

Comment: That's actually really clever, I'm for sure upvoting this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've solved your problem already:

> @Coldark,@DaveNewton,@Nick Parsons thanks for your time, I solved it

```
test.forEach(function(o, index) {
  var len = test.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (test[i] === undefined) {
      test[i] = null;
    }
  }
});
```

In case someone gets here looking for a solution to similar problem I'm going to say, that you could even do it as simple as:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (!arr[i]) { // or arr[i] === undefined if your array may have other falsy values in it
    arr[i] = null;
  }
}
```

Empty entries are caused by deleting array values i.e:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    delete arr[i];
}
```

which generally should not be used, unless it's intentional and we're fully aware of consequences. The main difference between empty or non existing entries and any of "empty" values like `null` or `undefined` is that the latter still can be accessed by indices.

It's greatly explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements)

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is using the `Array.from`.

```js
const arr = new Array(4);
arr[0] = 5219;

console.log(arr)

const arr_fill = Array.from(arr, x => x || null);

console.log(arr_fill);
```